Efficiency of a 2-stroke spark-ignition IC engine
Efficiency of a 2-stroke spark-ignition IC engine
The slope of $\eta$ vs $r$ graph is steep at less $r$, so is it possible to use more than one cylinder, with less compression ratio with the nth ones intake gas coming from the exhaust gas of the ($n-1$)th cylinder, and hence increase the overall efficiency, by rather using 1 cylinder with more compression ratio?


The term you want is "compound" engine.  If you check Wikipedia you'll find there is such a thing as a Compound Internal Combustion Engine.  In general compound diesel and steam engines are/were quite common in marine engines.  You may also see the term "triple expansion" in relation to steam engines.  However this is really [engineering.se] territory.
